# JSP Servlet Script, Passing Parameters

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, parameter-passing

The Error [I am a new user so I can't post images (just links)]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApkME.png

My ask.jsp(lines 15-20)------------------------------------------------------

```
<%!
        String corpus = new String();
        String getStory()
        {
            corpus = request.getParameter("story");
            return corpus;
        }

%>
```

It seems to say it cannot find the symbol "request" although I have sent it from my 'processStory' servlet as shown below:-

```
finally {
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/ask.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("story", storyTold);
        rd.forward(request, response);
        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: Lose the exclamation point. But this kind of code shouldn't be in a scriptlet. Also, you set an attribute, but try to get a parameter. They're different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try chaning `<%!` to `<%` and `request.getParameter()` to `request.getAttribute()`.
By the way why are you defining a method in your scriptlet?

Comment: Thank you but it didn't help, seemed much worse without the exclamation, so I got a brain and used sessions instead, helped a lot better. Appreciated your time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting a request attribute, you should do a request.getAttribute in your JSP.
BTW, scriptlets are no longer used in JSP's.